# PHP: Escape character is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, escaping

Whenever I try to escape the single quote in O'Neil the editor acts as if it did not work (based on the colour coding it uses) and when I run it it also does not work.

```
$query="UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Ian O\'Neil' WHERE id = 2 ";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Have you tried `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? In any case I would recommend prepared statements: MySQLI http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php / PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

I tested as below and its working, please check :

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $link->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query="UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'Ian O\'Neil' WHERE id = 2 ";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get an excellent resource to answer your question.
The sources said that you should use

**mysqli_real_escape_string** function
example from the source :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link));
}

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

this is the source : 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

You may need to read it.

Thanks I hope this helps